# splitting an NSString into UITextField pages

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, nsstring, uitextview

I have a number of NSStrings like this:

```
NSString *eightlabel = @"The process is not permitted to remove material, double-sided upper and lower specification limits, default transmission band for both limits, R-profile, upper limit: arithmetic mean deviation 3,1 μm, evaluation length of five sampling lengths (default), “max-rule”, lower limit: arithmetic mean deviation 0,9 μm, evaluation length of five sampling lengths (default), “16 %-rule” (default.)";
```

these are added to an array like this:

```
self.pickerViewArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             onelabel, twolabel, threelabel, fourlabel, fivelabel, sixlabel, sevenlabel,eightlabel,ninelabel,tenlabel,elevenlabel,twelvelabel,thirteenlabel,fourteenlabel,fifteenlabel,sixteenlabel,seventeenlabel,eightteenlabel,nineteenlabel,twentylabel, nil];
```

and then later recovered from uipickerview selection and displayed in a uitextview called example:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    [myPicker selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [myPicker reloadComponent:0];
    [myPicker selectRow:row inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    [myPicker reloadComponent:1];

    [example setText:[pickerViewArray2 objectAtIndex:row]];

}
```

my uitextview is small only 280 x 128 so the text overruns and i need to scroll the textfield, however i would prefer to page the textfield horizontally.

how can i split the nssstring into pages that fit the textview and allow the user to scroll horizontally through the content as required.

the strings are all variable in length and some are small enough to need only one page
maximum pages will be probably 2 pages.

any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView` doesn't support columns or paged scrolling.  You can use a `UIPageViewController`, or you can do it yourself using Core Text to draw to a custom view inside a `UIScrollView`.

`UIPageViewController` is discussed in detail toward the end of the *Implementing UIViewController Containment* video from [WWDC 2011](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).

I happen to have some sample code that uses Core Text to lay out columns in a `UIScrollView`.  You can find it here: https://github.com/mayoff/core-text-columns/  The `ColumnView.m` file contains most of the interesting code.

Comment: Hi Rob, i checked out your code and its exactly what i want as a solution, however i have to admit that its too complicated for me to understand at this stage of my learning. i will try and figure out whats happening in the code and how to mutilate it into something that works for me. do you have a tutorial on this or some guidelines for us newbee coders.

Comment: I don't have a tutorial, but if you google `core text columns` you will definitely find some other sample code and tutorial code.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` does not support horizontal scrolling. Consider using a `UIWebView` and HTML string instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for you response. So can you elaborate a little i can convert the strings easy enough, and replace the text view with web view but don't i still need to do calculations of the text length to get the paging effect? if so how do i split the html now?